# Rails form not going to correct action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

So I've got a particular form that's supposed to be comparing two objects. One being the current page that they're on and the other is the one we're searching for.

Here's the form in the **show.html.haml**:

```
%form.form-inline
  = form_tag compare_search_path, method: 'get' do
    = text_field_tag :q, params[:q], class: "typeahead", "data-provide" => "typeahead", autocomplete: "off"
    = hidden_field_tag :search_item_id, '', class: "search_item_id"
    = hidden_field_tag :current_item, @item.id
    = submit_tag "Search", name: nil, class: "btn"
```

Inside my controller, I've got:

```
def search_related
  puts "*" * 100
  puts "It's in here and working."
end
```

However, it is never getting inside the method, it just attempts to do a search and the method is never getting used.

My **routes.rb** has:

```
get "/compare_search" => 'items#search_related'
```

The URL that it seems to try and go to is this: `http://localhost:3000/items/1?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=[ITEM IS HERE]&search_item_id=3&current_item=1`

All of the parameters are correct, but it just doesn't seem to want to go to the correct action (all I want right now is for it to go into the action so I can do what I need in there).

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I dont think you need the / before compare_search. Also you need to add the `as: 'compare_search` to the end of the router I beleive.

Comment: As an aside, remember that if you submit a form with GET that you forfeit the CSRF protection that rails has built-in, plus you're limited by the max length of a GET request. I'd think hard about making this a POST instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 form elements in there.

```
%form.form-inline
  = form_tag compare_search_path, method: 'get' do
```

Remove the top line and make it:

```
  = form_tag compare_search_path, method: 'get', class: "form-inline" do
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking your route should be:

```
get "/compare_search", to: 'items#search_related', as: 'compare_search'
```